# Shopware 6 : How to debug administration plugins?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, shopware, shopware6

I am currently desperate with Shopware 6 - I wrote a plugin that adds a menu item to the administration and makes it possible to create job postings.

Unfortunately, there is a JavaScript error hidden somewhere in the administration. Theoretically yes, no problem, because with the command...

```
bin/watch-adminstration.sh
```

...Shopware should generate source maps, which make debugging much easier for me. Here's the problem: the source maps are missing.

So one step back: **How exactly do you debug the administration and where do you see the source maps?**

I hope someone has a solution, the lack of documentation from Shopware is really getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to know what setup you are using in order to achieve admin watching. I & Shopware recommends using the [dockware.io](https://dockware.io/) docker images for development.  You can read their documentation for more details. They also have a Makefile in the `/var/www/` folder that can be ran to watch admin. Here is what it does:

```bash
watch-admin: ## starts watcher for Shopware 6.4.13.0 Admin at http://localhost:8888
        cd /var/www/html && ./bin/build-administration.sh
        cd /var/www/html && php bin/console bundle:dump
        cd /var/www/html && php bin/console feature:dump
        cd /var/www/html && APP_URL=http://0.0.0.0 PROJECT_ROOT=/var/www/html APP_ENV=dev PORT=8888 HOST=0.0.0.0 ENV_FILE=/var/www/html/.env ./bin/watch-administration.sh
```

As you can see, it starts the Admin on a different port than normal.

Here is an example docker-compose file for such a setup:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  shop:
    container_name: shop
    image: dockware/dev:latest
    ports:
      - "22:22"     # ssh
      - "80:80"     # apache2
      - "443:443"   # apache2 https
      - "8888:8888" # watch admin
      - "9998:9998" # watch storefront proxy
      - "9999:9999" # watch storefront
      - "3306:3306" # mysql port
    #volumes:
    #  - "./src:/var/www/html"
    #  - "./src:/var/www/html/custom/plugins"
    networks:
      - web
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_ENABLED=0

## ***********************************************************************
##  NETWORKS
## ***********************************************************************
networks:
  web:
    external: false
```

Just SSH to the docker container after start, `cd .. && make watch-admin`. Then go to `http://localhost:8888`, this should load the admin page with source maps visible in the inspector tool.

Comment: I noticed, sometimes it shows the exact line where there is an error, but other times it seem to show something unrelated in core, and it is compiled and/or obfuscated – who knows what. Sometimes, however, the error will say something along the lines of "Cannot read property ... of undefined", specifically narrowing it down to certain properties; but still, would be nice if it would show the line number in a more consistent manner.